# Largest integer representation for 32-bit

Tags: computation

I have a very basic question regarding computers and number representations. I was wondering why it is that 2^31 -1 is the largest positive integer representation for 32-bit binary while 2^31 is the largest negative value? Why is it not possible for both the positive and negative representations to be expressed as 2^32? Is it related to the fact that for example given a positive representation you want to retain the ability to express a negative number as well? I assume we want to maintain the possibility of using all possible combinations of 0's and 1's in 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's fairly obvious that with 32 bits, you can only have 2^32 different values. For *unsigned* integers, the choice of those values is entirely straightforward: 0, 1, 2, etcetera, until you have 2^32 values - so the last possible value is 2^32-1.

For floats, the different values are far more complex, but again you can't have more values than you can have bit patterns, because one bit pattern must have one value. (Not the other way around, because -0.0 = +0.0).

Signed integers are not nearly as complex - you still have 2^32 bit patterns, and again 2^32 different values. All values differ by exactly one, so the difference between the min and the max value has to be 2^32-1.

For obvious reasons, the range is chosen centered around 0, so you have roughly 2^32/2 = 2^31 values lower than 0 and 2^31 values higher than 0. And it's only "roughly" 2^31, because you also need a bit pattern for 0, or two bit patterns for +0 and -0. That's why there's a -1 in 2^31-1.

2's complement chooses to reduce the range of positive numbers, because it encodes positive signed integers the same as unsigned integers with the same value. This leaves the top bit to represents -2^31.